# delete cell from listview and database fire base in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list view which contains cells like this :

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="30,0,20,0" VerticalOptions="Center">
 <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding AppointmentPatientName}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"   Style="{StaticResource labelView}"/>
  <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding AppointmentDate.Date}" Font="Small" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  Style="{StaticResource labelView}" />
  <Label x:Name="Delete Button" Text="X"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

How can I activate this label in order to make it Delete from firebase database it's smth like this :

```
 private async void ItemImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var appoitment = (Appoitment)((ImageButton)sender).CommandParameter;
            AppintmentService appintmentService = new AppintmentService();
            await appintmentService.DeleteFollowup(appoitment.PatientID, appoitment.ID);
            await DisplayAlert("Delted", "The patient Deleteed", "Ok");
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new PatientProfileFollowUpPage());
        }
```

but i want it for label not ImgButton and want activate it in viewmodel page

Comment: attach a TapGestureRecognizer to the Label

Comment: can you give me more details @Jason ?

Comment: i can't catch it, i'm just beginner so if you can type what i should do ?

Comment: the first result is a link to the Xamarin docs on using GestureRecognizers.  Please read them, and if you have a specific question about them, ask it.  But do not expect us to write a step by step tutorial for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want it for label not ImgButton and want activate it in viewmodel
> page

Yes, you can use `TapGestureRecognizer` and MVVM to achieve this.

Based on your code ,I made a simple demo.You can refer to the following code:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <tapapp1:MyViewModel></tapapp1:MyViewModel>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="30,0,20,0" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Label  Text="{Binding AppointmentPatientName}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"   />
        <Label  Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding AppointmentDate}" Font="Small" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"   />
        <Label x:Name="Delete" Text="X"  >

          <Label.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                      />
          </Label.GestureRecognizers>  

    </Label>
 </StackLayout>
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string AppointmentPatientName { get; set; }

    public string AppointmentDate { get; set; }


    public ICommand TapCommand => new Command(RemoveItem);

    private void RemoveItem()
    {
       // add your code here

    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        AppointmentPatientName = "Test1";
        AppointmentDate = "2022-4-28";
    }
}
```

Note: You can modify above code based on your requirement.

Comment: Thank you very very much !! but i faced a problem `public ICommand TapCommand => new Command(RemoveItemAsync);` error    `cant convert from method group to action <object>` and this is the function body

Comment: `private async Task RemoveItemAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var appoitment = (Appoitment)((ImageButton)sender).CommandParameter;
            AppintmentService appintmentService = new AppintmentService();
            await appintmentService.DeleteFollowup(appoitment.PatientID, appoitment.ID);
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new PatientProfileFollowUpPage());
        }`

Comment: Since you used MVVM, you don't need parameter `object sender, EventArgs e` in your method `RemoveItemAsync`  and try to replace `Task ` with `void`.

Comment: If you want to pass Parameter from your Label, you can add ` CommandParameter` to the Label. For example:  `<Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}" CommandParameter="delete"
                      />
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>`

Comment: And change code in ViewModel like this:   public ICommand TapCommand => new Command<object>(RemoveItemAsync);        private async void RemoveItemAsync(Object obj) {
            // here the obj is the passed parameter
        }